# Boxplot dictionaries instead of lists?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let us say I want to create a boxplot of a list which contains the numbers 1-5 about a million times each.

Such a list would be of about size 5 000 000, however represented as a dict it takes no space at all:

```
s = {1: 1000000, 2: 1000000, 3: 1000000, 4: 1000000, 5:1000000}
```

The problem is, if I try to create a boxplot of that dict I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    ax.boxplot(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 5462, in boxplot
    if not hasattr(x[0], '__len__'):
KeyError: 0
```

Is there a clever way of boxplotting the dictionary `s`, without having to put all the elements in a list?

---

A comment suggested I try

```
boxplot(n for n, count in s.iteritems() for _ in xrange(count))
```

but this resulted in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    boxplot(n for n, count in s.iteritems() for _ in xrange(count))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2134, in boxplot
    ret = ax.boxplot(x, notch, sym, vert, whis, positions, widths, patch_artist, bootstrap)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 5462, in boxplot
    if not hasattr(x[0], '__len__'):
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more the data you have? You apparently have many repetitions of the same numbers. Do all of them belong to a single dataset (i.e. do you want a single or multiple boxes?). Are there any other numbers in the data?

Comment: I have several dictionaries like s and want each dictionary to correspond to one box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know matplotlib does not have methods for such data. Basically, you will have to calculate the relevant statistics and implement you own method for plotting boxplots. This might get you started:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


s = [{1: 1000000, 2: 1000000, 3: 1000000, 4: 1000000, 5:1000000},
     {1: 1000000, 0: 1000000, 8: 1000000, 3: 1000000, 7:1000000}]

def boxplot(data, x=0):

    sorted_data = np.array(data.items())
    sorted_data = np.sort(sorted_data, 0)
    values = sorted_data[:,0]
    freqs = sorted_data[:,1]
    freqs = np.cumsum(freqs)
    freqs = freqs*1./np.max(freqs)

    #get 25%, 50%, 75% percentiles
    idx = np.searchsorted(freqs, [0.25, 0.5, 0.75])
    p25, p50, p75 = values[idx]
    vmin, vmax = values.min(), values.max()

    ax = plt.gca()
    l,r = -0.2+x, 0.2+x
    #plot boxes
    plt.plot([l,r], [p50, p50], 'k')
    plt.plot([l, r, r, l, l], [p25, p25, p75, p75, p25], 'k')
    plt.plot([x,x], [p75, vmax], 'k')
    plt.plot([x,x], [p25, vmin], 'k')

for i in range(len(s)):
    boxplot(s[i],i)
plt.xlim(-0.5,1.5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of using pictures to describe data is to get a feeling for the data as a whole, not to be terribly exact. So
there will not be much harm in condensing your data by generating one representative data point for every 1000 actual data points:

```
x = [val for val, num in s.items() for i in range(num//1000)]
```

This should be good enough for the naked eye:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
s = {1: 1000000, 2: 1000000, 3: 1000000, 4: 1000000, 5:1000000}
x = [val for val, num in s.items() for i in range(num//1000)]
dct = plt.boxplot(x)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This was also a great answer, but accepted the other one due to more detail. Much appreciated all the same. A good, common sense answer.